# Android Upload Image from device gallery to Amazon S3 server

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I want to Choose image from device gallary and upload it to **amazon s3** server but i have an exception in run time and i don't know why i got it.

***Stack Trace:***

```
05-22 13:17:46.939 23624-23624/com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b, PID: 23624
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/19106 }} to activity {com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b/com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3661)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3704)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:355)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
 at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:128)
 at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:356)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4375)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1704)
 at com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:78)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3657)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3704) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:157) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is my Code :**

**Button event to choose image from gallery:**

```
 public void SelectImage(View view) {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
```

**onActivityResult:** (the exception appears during executing last line written in this method)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                File f = new File(picturePath);

                String imageName = f.getName();

                AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials( MY_ACCESS_KEY, MY_SECRET_KEY ) );
                s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
                PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest( "BUCKET_NAME", FOLDER_NAME+"/"+imageName,f  );
                s3Client.putObject(por);
```

***Mainfest permisions:***

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

***Gradle dependencies:***

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that uploading to amazon should be another thread not in the main thread. So i added UploadImage class that extends AsyncTask as following:

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    private final String accessKey="my_access_Key";
    private final String secretKey="my_secret_key";
    private final String bucketName="my_bucket_name";
    private final String folderName="Android_Uploads"; /*"Android_Uploads";*/
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String fileName = params[0];
        String filePath = params[1];
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey));
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderName +"/"+ fileName,  new File(filePath));
        s3Client.putObject(por);
        return "";
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {

        return ;
    }
}
```

and i used it in onActivityResult in main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                File f = new File(picturePath);

                String imageName = f.getName();
                new UploadImage().execute(imageName, picturePath);
```